# Vue - adding prop as a Bem modifier

Tags: properties, vuejs2, vue-component, classname

I am passing in a 'type' prop to my component to use as a BEM modifier.

```
 <div class="badge badge--{{this.$props.type}}">
```

However when I try and concatenate the class I get an error. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cleaner way to do it is to create a `computed property` :

```
computed: {
  badgeClasses() {
    return `badge badge--${this.type}`;  
  },
},
```

And then bind it in your HTML :

```
<div :class="badgeClasses">
```

But you can also just bind the property, as you tried, but with a backquote instead of a simple quote :

```
<div class="`badge badge--${type}`">
```

Comment: Thanks, computed was the default choice but thought there may be a quick way to concatenate directly.  The other way is pretty ugly so will go computed.

Comment: Also note that you don't need `this.$props` in your HTML, since the data, the computed properties and the props are already in the current context.